# How to reload collectionview after sortedArrayUsingDescriptors array

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sorting, collectionview

I try to sort my array as below and found that NSLog result will show correctly for cell.productImage, cell.productName and cell.productPrice. However, collectionview does not reload accordingly after executed. Any idea? Please help. Thank you.

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader){

        DCCustionHeadView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:DCCustionHeadViewID forIndexPath:indexPath];
        WEAKSELF

        headerView.priceClickBlock = ^{//Click on price header

            cell = nil;
            cell = (_isSwitchGrid) ? [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:DCListGridCellID forIndexPath:indexPath] : [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:DCSwitchGridCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];


                if(_setItem.count >0){

                    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
                    NSArray *sortedArray = [_setItem sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

                    for (NSUInteger i=0; i<sortedArray.count; i++)
                    {
                        cell.productImage = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"image"];
                        cell.productName = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"];
                        cell.productPrice =  [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"price"];
                    }
                    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                        [collectionView reloadData];
                    } completion:nil];
                }

            }

        };

        reusableview = headerView;
    }  
}
```

Comment: When is `priceClickBlock` called?

Comment: Hi Rishab, priceClickBlock will trigger when click on "Price" header

Comment: So is ` reloadData` executed?

Comment: Hi Rishab, nope, look like did not executed. All data will remain unchanged.